# Type error in using chartjs and tc-angular-chartjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js, package.json

I'm using

```
"angularjs": 1.5  
"chart.js": "^2.7.2",
"tc-angular-chartjs": "^2.1.4"
```

but when I load the page this appears in console :

> TypeError:Chart is not a constructor at tc-angular-chartjs.js:141.

anyone help?

Comment: Can you please show a small snippet how you are importing the module in your file, sometimes the sequence of importing also matter.

Comment: I use ocLazyLoad to import to each page that I need . so I load this in my config :
  {
              name: 'tc.chartjs',
              files: ['node_modules/tc-angular-chartjs/dist/tc-angular-chartjs.js']
            },
            {
              files:['node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js']
            }

Comment: also when I check sources in my devTools I see chart.js is loaded

Answer (score 0):

Looks that chart.js library isn't loaded properly. Please check if there is a `chart.js` folder in your `node_modules`, or maybe you are missing import in your .html?

See line 195 in demo files:
https://github.com/carlcraig/tc-angular-chartjs/blob/master/demo/index.html#L195

Comment: both are exist . imported to html and exist in my node_modules